# actionscript 3 - error #1009 issues calling function from another class

Tags: actionscript-3

Im having trouble calling functions from other classes. I want to call a function in one class which updates a score display in another class. The error code for this is:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at code.functions::EnemyYellow()[code\functions\EnemyYellow.as:18]
    at code::Main()[\code\Main.as:27]

Would appreciate if someone could help me out, I set up 2 basic files with the code which is causing an issue. Its normally not set up like this, I just made this for testing and so I can clearly explain the problem.

Main file:

```
package code {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import code.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var _enemy:EnemyYellow;
    public var playerHP:Number;

    public function Main() {

        playerHP = 10;
        _playerHPdisplay.text = playerHP.toString();
        trace(playerHP)

        _enemy = new EnemyYellow;
    }


    public function lowerHP ():void
    {   
        playerHP = playerHP - 1;
        _playerHPdisplay.text = playerHP.toString();
        trace(playerHP)

    }
  }
}
```

Second File:

```
package code.functions {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import code.Main;

public class EnemyYellow extends MovieClip {

    public var _main:Main;

    public function EnemyYellow() {
        _main.lowerHP();
        trace ("done")
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried adding _main = new Main; in the second file but the game just loads with a blackscreen and an error about invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you surely need to "instantiate" the `Main` class, which means basically to create it.

```
public var _main:Main;
```

This line just declares that there **will** be a variable of type `Main`. But for now, the value of `_main` is `null`. So you are right, that you need to call:

```
_main = new Main();
```

After you've done this, the first error will disappear. But then you have things in that MovieClip that are still vague. Like `_playerHPdisplay`. Where's that from? Is it an instance from stage or what? You just created a brand new object, and it does not have **any** reference to other objects, TextFields or whatever.

So this basically answers your current question and problem, but for sure you will have more :)

Comment: _playerHPdisplay.text is a display on the screen.

Comment: Think of classes as the branches of a tree. Each branch know how long it goes from there on, but does't know what's before it. The root of the tree (root of your project) knows everything. So now, when you got a new branch (`Main`), you need to either pass information about things before (`_playerHPdisplay`) or it won't work. Pass it as a variable to the constructor for example. There are many ways to do that - read more about classes in AS3.